# Image button flickers when clicked to highlight (change image)

Tags: html, css

Why does an image button flicker when I click it for it to change to another image? - because its loading right? how can I solve it? can I load it before or something like that?

Comment: Yes. Pre-load both images in advance, this way they will be cached and won't take time to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an image sprite and change the background position, rather than loading a new image.

Basically, instead of switching between two images, and waiting for the second image to load on hover, you stack both states of the image in one graphic with a little space between. Then on your `:hover` rule, you just change the background position. Since the image resource has already been loaded at that point, it won't flicker anymore.

Answer (score -1):

you can have the click image loaded but with style="display:none", then when you click in, just change the src

Comment: This doesn't work with all browsers. Ideally that image wouldn't get loaded until it's needed and modern browsers can see the `display:none;` and infer that is isn't displayed.